# What are the tools to check performance of the page rendered?

Tags: performance, browser, user-interface, yslow

I am using Yslow recommendations, to improve UI/page performance. Are there any tools to benchmark and test that? I want to take the initial benchmark of the page, the processing time, rendering time, or each file. Then, after applying each of the rule, I need to take benchmark and check the details.

TIA.

Comment: Preferably open source tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably try using the  [Web Timings API](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webperf/raw-file/tip/specs/NavigationTiming/Overview.html) on W3C with Selenium 2. You can search google for the exact usage steps.

Another resource I have found extremely useful in past has been the following post on IBM's website especially the section called [Measuring Performance](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-aj-jsajaxperf/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

what about dev tools built into Chrome?